# Can I use an ArrayList as a SelectList in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a ASP.NET Web Application as part of my studies.

At the moment I am creating an **Add Product** section. I have added some images to an image folder, and would like those image names to be added to a dropdownlist. This is the code my tutorial offered:

EDIT: As someone pointed out below, ArrayList is no longer recommended. That's part of why I am trying to use this method.

```
    public void GetImages()
    {
        try
        {
            //get all filepaths
            string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"));

            //get all filenames and add them to an arraylist.

            ArrayList imagelist = new ArrayList();
            foreach (string image in images)
            {
                string imagename = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
                imagelist.Add(imagename);
            }

         //Set the arrayList as the dropdownview's datasource and refresh
        ddlImage.DataSource = imageList;
        ddlImage.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        ddlImage.DataBind();

    }
```

This is then used on page load.

This works fine when I'm creating it using web forms. However, I would like to use the `@Html.DropDownList` action link for this project. When connecting databases using scaffolding these dropdownlists are created and populated just fine, and I can see where the **SelectList** is generated for the view, ie:

```
    // GET: Products/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(db.ProductTypes, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

I am just not sure how to turn my tutorial example into the IEnumerable, which the SelecList initializer calls for. The closest I've gotten is this:

```
     List<SelectListItem> imagelist = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (string image in images)
            {
                string imagename = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
                imagelist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = imagename });
            }

             IEnumerable<string> imager = imagelist as IEnumerable<string>;
```

But that doesn't seem right.

EDIT: As pointed out below, I need to add the Value to the new `SelectListItem`:

```
     imagelist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = imagename, Value = "Id" });
```

This seems better. Although I am not sure whether I need to create "imager", the imageList as an IEnumerable. Isn't a SelectList already Enumerable?

ADDED QUESTION:
Also, how should I add this new list to the `ViewBag`?:

```
    ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(db.ProductTypes, "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList()
    return View();
```

My problem at the moment is it is within the `GetImages` method, and I am unsure how access it. I think the answer is super basic but I'm very new to this.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks again.

Comment: Don't use ArrayList anymore, period. Why doesn't that code seem right? You do have to set a Value in the SelectListItem.

Comment: Instead of `string imagename = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1)` use `string imagename = Path.GetFileName(image)` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Okay I am getting there. I understand setting the value. Now I just need to add it the the ViewBag. How would I write it?

ViewBag.Image = new SelectList(?)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create a new select list. the variable Imagelist will take on whatever type SelectList.

   var Imagelist = new SelectList(
    new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = imagename, Value = "Id"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = imagename2, Value = "Id2"},

    }, "Value" , "Text");


    //You can now use this viewbag in your view however you want.
      ViewBag.Image = Imagelist.
```